# paritions when booting windows (10) machine from ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

I'm currently on windows 10, however eventually i would like to install ubuntu (or maybe go back to windows 7). I created a bootable USB for ubuntu and restarted my PC to boot from there and the plan is to use gpart to wipe HD clean of all previous stuff.

I just had a question about what i see in gpart and which partitions should i delete. Again, i've always been more of a windows user so not sure what (and when) these partitions were created for me. Would be great if someone could explain how to read this screen. Also, could i go ahead and format all these individually? Or just delete the partitions?

[image]

Comment: Danger danger... if you don't know what gparted is telling you here, please don't use it! I wouldn't delete Windows 10 and go back to Windows 7. W10 is better than W7, and you'll need Windows to install BIOS updates, and run other Windows-only software. It looks like you created sda5, and that space may be usable to install Ubuntu, without disturbing Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "the plan is to use gpart to wipe HD clean of all previous stuff."

Hoped you **backedup** your important stuffs.

Ubuntu installation gives you option to install to the Entire HDD space selecting that option will  **"wipe HD clean of all previous stuff"** and the fresh installed Ubuntu will occupy entire space.

---

Am guessing you don't want to do the above `"which partitions should i delete".`? you ask

From gparted above it seam you had windows install in `/dev/sda2`,
`/dev/sda1` Windows system reverse. IF your plan is to dual boot you will not want to touch those.

The possible installation candidate will be `/dev/sda5` don't know what you use it for but it has enough space that you can either shrink to use for Ubuntu or **backup** the stuffs in it and use it entirely for your Ubuntu. If thats what you want "feel free" to delete the the partition(**`/dev/sda5`**).

---

*Edited to answer question in comment:*

1. What is /dev/sda1 Windows system reverse?

   You could find [this helpful](https://www.howtogeek.com/192772/what-is-the-system-reserved-partition-and-can-you-delete-it/). how do i know?. flags, label.
2. How did you guess windows is installed in /dev/sda2?

   Its fairly obvious. knock out the other possibilities and its left alone. it can't be /dev/sda5 the used space is too small for windows to fit in.
   /dev/sda4 ? the label and the flag gives it away.
3. How do these paritions map to c:\ drive in windows? which paritions is my c:

   The partition windows is install is automatically named C.

**Am not laying down any universal rule here** talking out of familiarity.

Comment: I have backedup important stuff (thanks for asking). Few quick questions. a.) How did you guess windows is installed in /dev/sda2? b.) What is /dev/sda1 Windows system reverse? c.) How do these paritions map to c:\ drive in windows? which paritions is my c: drive using?

Comment: @ N.M t Answer to your question in the edit.